# How to avoid form submit when Google Maps autocomplete address select in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

In my case the google autocomplete address search working. But when I click or press enter, the form also submit. I try the event `preventdefault` but it's not working!

It's my directive code.

```
myApp.directive('googleplace', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model,event) {
            var options = {
                types: [],

            };
            scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

            google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
              var location = scope.gPlace.getPlace().geometry.location;
                //
                scope.$apply(function() {

                  scope.lat = location.lat();
                  scope.lng  = location.lng();

                  event.preventDefault();
                    //alert(scope.lat);

                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var input = document.getElementById('IdWhereYouAreSearchingForLocation');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(input, 'keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) 
    { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

My issue resolved.
Problem was that i was just writing event.preventDefault().
You must try to know that which key is pressed? if Enter key is pressed then event.PreventDefault.